# Least-squares fit of PCA scores on original variables

Tags: r, regression, spss, pca

I have 100 vars, and I want to do factor analysis using variables var15-v25. To do that first I extracted the variables into another object (say `f`), & then run the principal component analysis.

Now I want to merge PCA scores with the original dataset to run regression using PCA scores as predictors.

Can anybody please suggest me the method to merge these 2 datasets. The code I used are the following:

```
spss_data_factor <- sqldf("SELECT Respondent_Serial,Q4_01_Q4,Q4_02_Q4,Q4_03_Q4,Q4_04_Q4,Q4_05_Q4,Q4_06_Q4,Q4_07_Q4,Q4_08_Q4,Q4_09_Q4,Q4_10_Q4 FROM spss_data_rel")
f <- princomp(spss_data_factor1, cor = TRUE)
summary(f, loadings=TRUE)
f$scores[, 1:5]
```

Comment: Show us a sample of original data.

Comment: What is your question actually about? AFAICS, it merely has something to do with FA. You just want to append factor scores table in one file? Please, provide more details...

Comment: I think that you are actually calling R within SPSS here right? Then what you mean with merging 2 files is that you want to get the scores on the factors as extra variables in your SPSS file? I am not sure how to do that, but it might be possible to just write it to a file with `write.table()` and import that to SPSS. Probably an easier way though.

Comment: `princomp` returns an object of eponymous class. It is a list, and it has `scores` element of class `matrix`. You can easily save that with `write.<something>`. Anyway, the title is misleading, this has nothing to do with FA, `princomp` carries out a PCA!

Comment: Please, could we all agree never ever to call a PCA a factor analysis again? factor analysis is done by `factanal`, not by `princomp`, and is something completely different. Don't make me get on that horse... ;)

Comment: Care to change the title then? I have only a vague idea about the title: "Least-squares fit of principal components' scores on raw variables"

Comment: @Sacha: I'm not running R in SPSS. The actual data was in SPSS. So I named it like that. I prefer R more than SPSS, so import the data & then run on R. @ Joris: I learned it hard way that factor analysis should be done using **fractanal** & not by **princomp**. Thanks for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please avoid using names from R base packages - `factor` is kind of reserved. It will work just fine, but it may confuse you at some point of development... And your `factor` is not a file, it's a R object of `princomp` class.

Anyway, you want to define a regression model with factor scores as predictors? Piece of cake... and no merging is required:

```
fa <- princomp(mtcars, cor=TRUE)
fa_scores <- fa$scores
fit <- lm(mtcars$hp ~ fa_scores)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = mtcars$hp ~ fa_scores)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-2.521e-14 -7.825e-15 -2.416e-15  5.622e-15  4.329e-14 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       1.467e+02  2.862e-15  5.125e+16   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.1  -2.227e+01  1.113e-15 -2.000e+16   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.2  -1.679e+01  1.758e-15 -9.549e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.3   9.449e+00  3.614e-15  2.614e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.4  -4.567e+00  5.513e-15 -8.285e+14   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.5  -3.644e+01  6.055e-15 -6.019e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.6  -4.821e+00  6.222e-15 -7.747e+14   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.7  -1.010e-01  7.783e-15 -1.297e+13   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.8   1.501e+01  8.164e-15  1.838e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.9  -3.886e+01  1.031e-14 -3.768e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.10  1.672e+01  1.255e-14  1.333e+15   <2e-16 ***
fa_scoresComp.11 -1.731e+01  1.928e-14 -8.979e+14   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 1.619e-14 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     1,  Adjusted R-squared:     1 
F-statistic: 5.053e+31 on 11 and 20 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You may also want to convert original dataset to matrix, in order to carry out `ncol(mtcars)` regressions, on each column of response matrix. `lm` function supports `response ~ terms` formula, where `response` can be a matrix. See `?lm`:

> If response is a matrix a linear model
>   is fitted separately by least-squares
>   to each column of the matrix.

So, you can do something like this:

```
fit2 <- lm(as.matrix(mtcars) ~ fa_scores)
summary(fit2) # handle with care! =)
```

I hope that this was helpful...

---

Anyway, if you want to perform a factor analysis, please see [this link](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html). You should install William Revelle's `psych` package.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you aL3xa! I found the answer of the solution. I'm putting it here as somebody might find it helpful.

```
## Factor Analysis
library(psych)
spss_data_fac=read.csv("D:\\Arijit\\spss_data_rel_01.csv")
fa.parallel(spss_data_fac[,40:49])
spss_data_fac_01=factanal(spss_data_fac[,40:49],factors=2,scores="regression",rotation="promax")
spss_data_fac_01$scores
## Factor Analysis factors are used for logistic regression
spss_dat_reg=glm(spss_data_fac$Q8~spss_data_fac_01$scores+spss_data_fac$Q14)
summary(spss_dat_reg)
```

Regards,
A